# UIView field not allocating memory in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have just started with iOS development in objective C and I'm finding it difficult to get my head around UIView objects.

Here is what I'm doing:

1. In an existing project, I'm adding a new UIViewController.
2. In a storyboard I'm dragging and dropping UI elements.
3. I added some constraints into each of the UI elements (just playing around, there is no specific constraint as such, this could be anything).
4. Dragging each of these UIElement to ViewController.h to create a handler.
5. In ViewController.m file I'm trying to first synthesize all those objects and then further play around with some logics (again nothing very specific).
6. In ViewDidLoad I'm try to perform loading my UI elements.
7. During runtime when I trigger my custom UIViewController, then I could see from debugger that it actually comes into controller's ViewDidLoad section.

Problem:

During runtime, all the UI elements have nil assign to them. I don't understand this that why is synthesize not allocating them any memory. The execution just goes over my logics, but does nothing. I don't see anything displayed in  my screen.

Question:

Why is this so? Why even after setting my UI constraints in storyboard and synthesizing each UI handler objects, I was not able to allocate memory to my UI objects?

Comment: share some code.

Comment: @KKRocks I can't. Copyright protected.

Comment: Try to do clean project and run again

Comment: @ikis - if you are using current Objective-C with Storyboards, you do *not* need to `synthesize` anything. If you've connected a UI element in the Storyboard such as `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *testView;` in your header file, you can then refer to it in `viewDidLoad` with `_testView`. I'd suggest start with a fresh project, add a View Controller, add one UI element, connect it via IBOutlet, and get that working.

Comment: If you can't share code, create a non-copyrighted [example that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/mcve). There are just too many possible sources of the problem for us to guess which is the root of the issue here. If you want help, share code.

Comment: Are you sure that each view has a proper outlet to the viewController in your StoryBoard? See for instance here: https://turbofuture.com/misc/IOS-5-A-Beginners-Guide-to-Storyboard-Connection

Comment: @Koen let's forget storyboards for a second. If I try to declare my fields in .h file and define and use them in .m such that I add rest all UI properties programmatically , even then fields don't get memory allocation.

Comment: The only way I can display UI stuff is if I declare them locally in my viewcontroller function callbacks.

Comment: Okay. I was not able to solve this problem. But I created another objective-c class and followed the same steps and  this time it worked magically. I didn't do anything different from previous time.

Comment: Keeping this question open so that people can write and share answers and it may help newbies stumbling upon similar problems.